# Wildfly 8.2.0 expose JMX over RMI

Tags: jboss, rmi, wildfly, jmx

Is it possible to expose JMX interface over RMI, not over http-remoting? Or expose via both?
It would be great to access Mbeans via url like "service:jmx:rmi//" to be able to establish zabbix gate monitoring. Zabbix has an issue with hard-coded value in connection url ([ZBXNEXT-1274] Configurable JMX Endpoint - ZABBIX SUPPORT)

As far as I understand I need to add additional connector to jmx subsystem. Is is correct?
Part of xml for jmx subsystem is default for now and looks like this:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:jmx:1.3">
    <expose-resolved-model/>
    <expose-expression-model/>
    <remoting-connector/>
</subsystem>
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that it is possibly to add alternative JMX access protocols in WildFly. At least not as a supported configuration option.
It might be possible to expose JMX via the standard JVM parameters, as described in the [Java Documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/guides/management/agent.html), but I would not expect it to be working correctly.

An alternative solution for enabling monitoring from Zabbix is to expose some or all of the JMX MBeans through a http or RESTful interface with [Jolokia](http://jolokia.org/) or other similar technology.

Answer (score 0):

zabbix in version 3.4 have Configurable JMX Endpoint.

https://www.zabbix.com/documentation/3.4/manual/config/items/itemtypes/jmx_monitoring

You need only upgrade zabbix, add jar for application server in zabbix and change endpoint in template. I have success setting with wildlfy 10,10.1 and 11. Both modes is supported (domain and standalone).